# Image generator

Tags: html, image, web-applications

I'd like to be able to generate an image with overlaying text (that is inputted by the user) such as how it is done on [www.depressiondog.info](http://www.depressiondog.info). Can someone show/link me to some code that will do that. Thanks.

Comment: Which is your server side language?

Comment: What language do you want to use? (HTML alone isn't gonna cut it.)

Comment: These are apparently generated on the server, so it's important to know what server-side technology you'd be using on your own site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Depression Dog site sends a request to a PHP page on an Apache server.  They probably use some code like you'll find in [this](http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/) tutorial explaining how watermark PNG and JPEG Images with PHP and GD2.

- Here's the request to their service : `http://www.vumf.com/ddog.jpg?l1=PHP&l2=Makes+Me+Cry&l1f=26&l2f=26&f=2`
- And Here is the Image
- [PHP Makes Me Cry http://www.vumf.com/ddog.jpg?l1=PHP&l2=Makes+Me+Cry&l1f=26&l2f=26&f=2](http://www.vumf.com/ddog.jpg?l1=PHP&l2=Makes+Me+Cry&l1f=26&l2f=26&f=2)

Comment: I was gonna go with "PHP Kills Puppies", but I didn't want to offend either dog owners or PHP developers/Puppy Killers. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, it depends on your server side language. However, the website you have provided uses PHP on the server side.

This probably involves the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library, in particular the [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function.

A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-add-text-to-image).

Answer (score 0):

I've had some pretty good experiences with [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) in the past.